# Getting SQLServerException makeFromDriverError message 'could not prepare statement' and 'The connection is closed'

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, hibernate, c3p0

Recently as my production app has been increasing in users, I have started to receive the following errors (thousands):

> org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare
>   statement
>       Problem Id:com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError
>
> The connection is closed.
>       Problem Id:com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError

Here are the full errors:

```
 javax.persistence.PersistenceException:    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert
 (AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java1763)    at
 org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert
 (AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java1694)    at
 org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find
 (AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java1141)    at
 org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find
 (AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java1068)    at
 sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor65.invoke    at
 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke
 (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java43)    at
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java498)    at
 org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke
 (SharedEntityManagerCreator.java241)    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy51.find
 at com.adaptive.xxxxxxx.data.JPAPersistenceAdapter.find
 (JPAPersistenceAdapter.java27)    at
 com.adaptive.xxxxxxxxx.data.ChangeSetApplier2.applyChange
 (ChangeSetApplier2.java257)    at
 com.adaptive.xxxxxxxx.data.ChangeSetApplier2.applyChanges
 (ChangeSetApplier2.java59)    at
 com.adaptive.xxxxxxxx.services.EntityServiceImpl.applyChangeSet
 (EntityServiceImpl.java64)    at
 sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor98.invoke    at
 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke
 (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java43)    at
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java498)    at
 org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection
 (AopUtils.java317)    at
 org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint
 (ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java183)    at
 org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed
 (ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java150)    at
 org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke
 (MethodSecurityInterceptor.java64)    at
 org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed
 (ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java172)    at
 org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation
 (TransactionInterceptor.java96)    at
 org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction
 (TransactionAspectSupport.java260)    at
 org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke
 (TransactionInterceptor.java94)    at
 org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed
 (ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java172)    at
 org.granite.tide.spring.TideDataPublishingInterceptor$1.call
 (TideDataPublishingInterceptor.java78)    at
 org.granite.tide.spring.TideDataPublishingWrapper.execute
 (TideDataPublishingWrapper.java127)    at
 org.granite.tide.spring.TideDataPublishingInterceptor.invoke
 (TideDataPublishingInterceptor.java75)    at
 org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed
 (ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java172)    at
 org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke
 (JdkDynamicAopProxy.java204)    at
 com.sun.proxy.$Proxy61.applyChangeSet    at
 sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor736.invoke    at
 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke
 (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java43)    at
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java498)    at
 org.granite.messaging.service.ServiceInvocationContext.invoke
 (ServiceInvocationContext.java72)    at
 org.granite.messaging.service.security.AbstractSecurityService.endAuthorization
 (AbstractSecurityService.java108)    at
 org.granite.spring.security.SpringSecurity3Service.authorize
 (SpringSecurity3Service.java294)    at
 org.granite.messaging.service.ServiceInvoker.invoke
 (ServiceInvoker.java220)    at
 org.granite.messaging.amf.process.AMF3MessageProcessor.processRemotingMessage
 (AMF3MessageProcessor.java141)    at
 org.granite.messaging.amf.process.AMF3MessageProcessor.process
 (AMF3MessageProcessor.java60)    at
 org.granite.messaging.amf.process.AMF0MessageProcessor.process
 (AMF0MessageProcessor.java79)    at
 org.granite.messaging.webapp.AMFEndpoint.serviceAMF
 (AMFEndpoint.java91)    at
 org.granite.messaging.webapp.AMFEndpoint.service (AMFEndpoint.java66) 
 at org.granite.spring.ServerFilter.handle (ServerFilter.java331)    at
 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch
 (DispatcherServlet.java925)    at
 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService
 (DispatcherServlet.java856)    at
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest
 (FrameworkServlet.java936)    at
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost
 (FrameworkServlet.java838)    at
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service (HttpServlet.java648)    at
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service
 (FrameworkServlet.java812)    at
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service (HttpServlet.java729)    at
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter
 (ApplicationFilterChain.java292)    at
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter
 (ApplicationFilterChain.java207)    at
 org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter (WsFilter.java52)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter
 (ApplicationFilterChain.java240)    at
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter
 (ApplicationFilterChain.java207)    at
 com.adaptive.xxxxxxxxx.servlet.CacheControlFilter.doFilter
 (CacheControlFilter.java13)    at
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter
 (ApplicationFilterChain.java240)    at
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter
 (ApplicationFilterChain.java207)    at
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke
 (StandardWrapperValve.java212)    at
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke
 (StandardContextValve.java106)    at
 org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke
 (AuthenticatorBase.java502)    at
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke
 (StandardHostValve.java141)    at
 org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke
 (ErrorReportValve.java79)    at
 org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke
 (AbstractAccessLogValve.java616)    at
 org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve.invoke
 (RewriteValve.java480)    at
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke
 (StandardEngineValve.java88)    at
 org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service
 (CoyoteAdapter.java522)    at
 org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process
 (AbstractHttp11Processor.java1095)    at
 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process
 (AbstractProtocol.java672)    at
 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun
 (NioEndpoint.java1502)    at
 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run
 (NioEndpoint.java1458)    at
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker
 (ThreadPoolExecutor.java1149)    at
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run
 (ThreadPoolExecutor.java624)    at
 org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run
 (TaskThread.java61)    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java748) Inner
 exception org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException handled at
 org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert:    at
 org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert
 (StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java54)    at
 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert
 (SqlExceptionHelper.java126)    at
 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement
 (StatementPreparerImpl.java196)    at
 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement
 (StatementPreparerImpl.java160)    at
 org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.prepareQueryStatement
 (AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java257)    at
 org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeQueryStatement
 (AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java201)    at
 org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad
 (AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java137)    at
 org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad
 (AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java102)    at
 org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.load
 (AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java186)    at
 org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load
 (AbstractEntityPersister.java4126)    at
 org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource
 (DefaultLoadEventListener.java503)    at
 org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad
 (DefaultLoadEventListener.java468)    at
 org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load
 (DefaultLoadEventListener.java213)    at
 org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad
 (DefaultLoadEventListener.java275)    at
 org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad
 (DefaultLoadEventListener.java151)    at
 org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad (SessionImpl.java1106)   
 at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2000
 (SessionImpl.java176)    at
 org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load
 (SessionImpl.java2587)    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get
 (SessionImpl.java991)    at
 org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find
 (AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java1110)    at
 org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find
 (AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java1068)    at
 sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor65.invoke    at
 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke
 (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java43)    at
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java498)    at
 org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke
 (SharedEntityManagerCreator.java241)    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy51.find
 at com.adaptive.xxxxxxx.data.JPAPersistenceAdapter.find
 (JPAPersistenceAdapter.java27)    at
 com.adaptive.xxxxxxxxx.data.ChangeSetApplier2.applyChange
 (ChangeSetApplier2.java257)    at
 com.adaptive.xxxxxxxxx.data.ChangeSetApplier2.applyChanges
 (ChangeSetApplier2.java59)    at
 com.adaptive.xxxxxxx.services.EntityServiceImpl.applyChangeSet
 (EntityServiceImpl.java64)    at
 sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor98.invoke    at
 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke
 (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java43)    at
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java498)    at
 org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection
 (AopUtils.java317)    at
 org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint
 (ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java183)    at
 org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed
 (ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java150)    at
 org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke
 (MethodSecurityInterceptor.java64)    at
 org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed
 (ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java172)    at
 org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation
 (TransactionInterceptor.java96)    at
 org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction
 (TransactionAspectSupport.java260)    at
 org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke
 (TransactionInterceptor.java94)    at
 org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed
 (ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java172)    at
 org.granite.tide.spring.TideDataPublishingInterceptor$1.call
 (TideDataPublishingInterceptor.java78)    at
 org.granite.tide.spring.TideDataPublishingWrapper.execute
 (TideDataPublishingWrapper.java127)    at
 org.granite.tide.spring.TideDataPublishingInterceptor.invoke
 (TideDataPublishingInterceptor.java75)    at
 org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed
 (ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java172)    at
 org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke
 (JdkDynamicAopProxy.java204)    at
 com.sun.proxy.$Proxy61.applyChangeSet    at
 sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor736.invoke    at
 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke
 (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java43)    at
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java498)    at
 org.granite.messaging.service.ServiceInvocationContext.invoke
 (ServiceInvocationContext.java72)    at
 org.granite.messaging.service.security.AbstractSecurityService.endAuthorization
 (AbstractSecurityService.java108)    at
 org.granite.spring.security.SpringSecurity3Service.authorize
 (SpringSecurity3Service.java294)    at
 org.granite.messaging.service.ServiceInvoker.invoke
 (ServiceInvoker.java220)    at
 org.granite.messaging.amf.process.AMF3MessageProcessor.processRemotingMessage
 (AMF3MessageProcessor.java141)    at
 org.granite.messaging.amf.process.AMF3MessageProcessor.process
 (AMF3MessageProcessor.java60)    at
 org.granite.messaging.amf.process.AMF0MessageProcessor.process
 (AMF0MessageProcessor.java79)    at
 org.granite.messaging.webapp.AMFEndpoint.serviceAMF
 (AMFEndpoint.java91)    at
 org.granite.messaging.webapp.AMFEndpoint.service (AMFEndpoint.java66) 
 at org.granite.spring.ServerFilter.handle (ServerFilter.java331)    at
 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch
 (DispatcherServlet.java925)    at
 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService
 (DispatcherServlet.java856)    at
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest
 (FrameworkServlet.java936)    at
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost
 (FrameworkServlet.java838)    at
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service (HttpServlet.java648)    at
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service
 (FrameworkServlet.java812)    at
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service (HttpServlet.java729)    at
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter
 (ApplicationFilterChain.java292)    at
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter
 (ApplicationFilterChain.java207)    at
 org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter (WsFilter.java52)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter
 (ApplicationFilterChain.java240)    at
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter
 (ApplicationFilterChain.java207)    at
 com.adaptive.xxxxxx.servlet.CacheControlFilter.doFilter
 (CacheControlFilter.java13)    at
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter
 (ApplicationFilterChain.java240)    at
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter
 (ApplicationFilterChain.java207)    at
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke
 (StandardWrapperValve.java212)    at
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke
 (StandardContextValve.java106)    at
 org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke
 (AuthenticatorBase.java502)    at
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke
 (StandardHostValve.java141)    at
 org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke
 (ErrorReportValve.java79)    at
 org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke
 (AbstractAccessLogValve.java616)    at
 org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve.invoke
 (RewriteValve.java480)    at
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke
 (StandardEngineValve.java88)    at
 org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service
 (CoyoteAdapter.java522)    at
 org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process
 (AbstractHttp11Processor.java1095)    at
 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process
 (AbstractProtocol.java672)    at
 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun
 (NioEndpoint.java1502)    at
 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run
 (NioEndpoint.java1458)    at
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker
 (ThreadPoolExecutor.java1149)    at
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run
 (ThreadPoolExecutor.java624)    at
 org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run
 (TaskThread.java61)    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java748) Inner
 exception com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException handled at
 org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert:
 at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError
 (SQLServerException.java191)    at
 com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.checkClosed
 (SQLServerConnection.java395)    at
 com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.prepareStatement
 (SQLServerConnection.java2292)    at
 com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.prepareStatement
 (SQLServerConnection.java1931)    at
 sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor731.invoke    at
 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke
 (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java43)    at
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java498)    at
 com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask.run
 (GooGooStatementCache.java546)    at
 com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run
 (ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java648)
 com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException:    at
 com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError
 (SQLServerException.java191)    at
 com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.checkClosed
 (SQLServerConnection.java395)    at
 com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.prepareStatement
 (SQLServerConnection.java2292)    at
 com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.prepareStatement
 (SQLServerConnection.java1931)    at
 sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor731.invoke    at
 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke
 (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java43)    at
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java498)    at
 com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask.run
 (GooGooStatementCache.java546)    at
 com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run
 (ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java648)
```

I am wondering if it has to do with c3p0 connection pooling.

I am not 100% if the information is being taken from the app-config file, vs the hibernate.properties file.

I have attached both files, as well, you can see the relevant information included inline below:

app-config.xml:

```
<!-- Data source --
    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close"

        <property name="driverClass" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" /

        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:sqlserver://xxxxxxxx.database.windows.net:1433;database=XXXXX;user=XXXXXXXX;password=XXXXXXXXX;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;" /

        <!-- Pool properties --
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="3" /
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="120" /
        <property name="maxStatements" value="120" /
        <property name="preferredTestQuery" value="SELECT 1" /
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="300" /
        <property name="testConnectionOnCheckin" value="true" /
        <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="30" /
    </bean>
```

hibernate.properties:

```
# JDBC Connection information
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/mkbkwebgds
jdbc.username=xxxxxxxx
jdbc.password=xxxxxxxxxxx
# Hibernate 3 configuration
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.format_sql=true
hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=20
        hibernate.connection.provider_class=org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider
hibernate.transaction.factory_class=org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment=3
hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period=1000
hibernate.c3p0.timeout=2520
hibernate.c3p0.min_size=3
hibernate.c3p0.max_size=20
hibernate.c3p0.max_statements=0
hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery=select 1;
```

I had not changed anything in the app or on the server since starting to find these errors.

Any help to solve this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your hibernate.properties file is setting up a MySql driver while your app-config.xml is setting up a SQL Server driver. Since the error message mentions SQL Server I'm gussing that your app-config.xml is what's used. (Your hibernate.properties also sets `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update` which should never ever be used in production).

app-config.xml sets `testConnectionOnCheckin` to true. This means that the connections are validated when they are returned to the pool. It also sets `idleConnectionTestPeriod` to 30 which means that your idle connections are validated every 30 seconds. This makes it unlikely, but not impossible, that the problem is the database closing the connections while they are pooled.

You could try replacing `testConnectionOnCheckIn` with `testConnectionOnCheckout`. This would fix any problems with the database closing the connection on you for sure. If this doesn't work then the problem is the program actively closing the connection and then trying to use it again.

Comment: for the hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update, it should be set to validate instead of update then?

Comment: Is there anything well known that in my settings or otherwise that would cause these errors due to increasing load on the server. ie more users connecting, or the database transactions taking longer due to user's data being larger?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue when trying to open connection manually in my Spring Repository. After I start using JdbcTemplate error dissapeared